# Need help to implement logic for hierarchical queries in Databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

There are 5 levels

1.MasterBrand (Highest level)
2.Brand
3.DoseForm
4.DoseStrength
5.Drug,MSA,Device  (lowest level)

```
 parent               parent           parent         parent
```

Drug-------->DoseStrength--------->DoseForm-------->Brand---------->MasterBrand [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXFjU.png)

Below is the Requirement

TherapyId & TherapyType is there in the table, we have to implement the logic for other columns

Ex. For Drug, TherapyParentid is DoseStrength id
For DoseStrength, TherapyParentid is DoseForm id
For DoseForm, TherapyParentid is Brand id
For Brand,TherapyParentid is MasterBrand
For MasterBrand, as there is no parent so its parentId is null

For DoseStrength column,
For TherapyType Drug,  DoseStrength is 2 (as its parent)
For DoseStrength , it will be null as it has no parent.
For DoseForm, it will be null as DoseStrength is child of Dosestrength
For Brand, it will be null as DoseStrength is child of Brand
For MasterBrand, it will be null as DoseStrength is child of MasterBrand

Similary for other columns....

6 to 8 is another set where device is the lowest level and after that 2 level is skipped and then Brand is defined and based on that its calculated for other columns.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/410e2.jpg)

Please help me to implement this logic

Comment: Please share on what have you tried?

Comment: I tried with using lag function where i got the third column which TherapyParentId     val parentWindowSpec = Window.orderBy(col("TherapyId"))                                                    val parentDf = rawDf.withColumn("TherapyParentId",when(col("TherapyType") === lit("MasterBrand"),lit(null)).
    otherwise(lead("TherapyId",1).over(parentWindowSpec)))

Comment: Then i did the self join  where i got the TherapyType,TherapyId & TherapyParentName                                                                                                   val joinDf = parentDf.as("a").join(parentDf.as("b"),col("a.TherapyParentId") === col("b.TherapyId"),"left")
    .selectExpr("a.TherapyId TherapyId","a.TherapyType TherapyType","a.TherapyParentId TherapyParentId","b.TherapyType TherapyParentName").show()

Comment: Is this the correct way to go?